# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_bytes'

Tags: python, django, forms, postgresql, base64

New on python and having a hard time with solving error codes.

I have a form which adds rows to a postgresql databse. the form has an autofield which is primary key  inside my models.py.  Adding rows as such works, and the uniqueid fields counts up like inteded (1,2,3,...)

models.py:

```
class forwards(models.Model):
    uniqueid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    urlA = models.CharField(max_length = 254)
    counterA = models.DecimalField( max_digits=19, decimal_places=0,default=Decimal('0'))
    urlB = models.CharField(max_length = 254)
    counterB = models.DecimalField( max_digits=19, decimal_places=0,default=Decimal('0'))
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
    shortcodeurl = models.CharField(max_length = 254)
```

forms.py:

```
class AddUrlForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = forwards
        # fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ["user", "counterA", "counterB", "shortcodeurl", "uniqueid"]
```

The goal is to use the primary key value (which should be an integer according to [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField)), transform it into "bytes" and then do a bytes-to-base64 conversion to create a shortcode-url. I want to store this shortcode inside the table. I try to do this in the views.py

views.py

```
def forwardthis(request):
    forwardform = AddUrlForm(request.POST or None)
    if forwardform.is_valid():
        forward = forwardform.save(commit=False)
        forward.user = request.user.username
        uniqueid_local = forward.uniqueid
        print(uniqueid_local)
        uniqueid_local_bytes = uniqueid_local.to_bytes(3, byteorder='big')
        shortcodeurl_local  = urlsafe_base64_encode(uniqueid_local_bytes)
        forward.shortcodeurl = shortcodeurl_local
        forward.save()
```

**My Problem:**

I don't succeed in creating this shortcode URL and am getting an "NoneType" error. I tried modifying the models.py into BigIntegerField and IntegerField, but that didn't work. Adding `" default=0 "` to `uniqueid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` generated no error the first time I submitted a form, but then, when submitting a second form, it gives an error `null value in column "timestamp" violates not-null constraint`

To me, it looks like the `uniqueid` is not recognised like an integer. How to fix this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoFields are set by the database itself, so don't get a value until after you save. But you have not saved at that point, because you passed `commit=False` to the form save; this creates an instance in memory but does not send it to the db yet.

If you want this to work, you will have to remove that `commit=False` and accept the (tiny) cost of saving to the db twice.